# How do I make a pointer to an entire string in C?

Tags: c, string, function, pointers, implicit-conversion

I have the following code and am supposed to fill in the entire main function just to demonstrate how pointers work.
`e` is an integer of 4,
`f` is an array of the characters in the code,
`g` is a pointer to the string "ABC".

I got a good understanding of how `e` and `f` work, but I'm curious about the variable `g` and whether it's actually a pointer to the string `s`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int a, char b[], char c, char *d)
{
}

int main(void)
{
  char s[] = {"ABC"};
  char *g = &s[2];
  int e = 4;
  char f[] = {'3', '7', '\0'};

 int y = foo(e, f, g[2], g);
}
```

Comment: You say *`g` is a pointer to the string `"ABC"`*. Not with `char *g = &s[2];` but with `char *g = s;` where the array `s` *decays* to a pointer. What you have, is a pointer to the string `"C"`.

Comment: `g` points to `C`, the third (keep in mind arrays are zero-indexed) element of the array `s`. But by no means does it point the entire string. Thanks to the fact, that the strings are null-terminated,  `g` itself can also be treated as a string.

Comment: If you print `g` with `puts(g)` you'll find out where it points. Or alternatively you can watch that pointer in your favourite debugger.

Comment: It might be more interesting to do `char s[] = "ABCDEFGHI"; char *g = &s[2]; ... foo(e, f, g[3], g);`. Since `g[2]` in your current code is `'\0'`, you may find this modification of interest.

Answer (score 0):

This function declaration

```
int foo(int a, char b[], char c, char *d);
```

is equvalent to the following function declarations

```
int foo(int a, char *b, char c, char *d);

int foo(int a, char b[], char c, char d[]);
```

And all the function declarations declare the same one function.

A function parameter having an array type is adjusted by the compiler to pointer to the array element type.

In this call of the function

```
 int y = foo(e, f, g[2], g);
```

the array designator f is converted to pointer to its first element.

You can imagine this call like

```
You c int y = foo(e, &f[0], g[2], g);
```

The variable g was initialized by the address of the third element of the array s

```
char *g = &s[2];
```

This pointer is passed to the function as the forth argument.

You could write for example

```
char s[] = {"ABC"};
char *g = s;
```

In this case the array designator `s` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. That is the declaration

```
char *g = s;
```

is equivalent to

```
char *g = &s[0];
```

As you need to declare a pointer to the whole array as an object then you need to write

```
char ( *g )[4] = &s;
```

This quote from the C Standard will be useful (6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators)

> 3 Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary &
> operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an
> expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an
> expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial
> element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object
> has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: So by default, if I just add in the name of the variable, in this case 'f', it will automatically point to the first element of the array?

Comment: @Adele Yes, It will be implicitly converted to a pointer except within the operator sizeof and the address of operator &.

Answer (score 0):

The variable g points to the third element of the string "abc" i.e, c. I f you want g as a pointer for whole string then make it as,

```
char *g =s;
```

Comment: I ran it through a c visualizer and it shows that if I do it that way, it points to the first element of the string. Is that correct or?

Comment: Yes it is correct the pointer will point the first character if we need to move to other characters we have to use a for loop and increase the pointer using increment operator